# Why is this happening to my form? (screenshots included)

Tags: css, forms

This is my code:

Enter your question here:

```
    <form method="post" action="">
    Title: 
    <input type="text" name="title">

    <br>Further Explanation:<br>
    <textarea name="content" rows="5"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" name="input" value="Ask" />


            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
                include "connection.php";
                if (mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE Questions"))
                {
                    echo "Pitanje je uspesno obrisano";
                } else {
                    echo "Nastala je greška pri brisanju pitanja<br>" . mysql_error();
                }

            }
            ?>

    </form>
    <form action="
    <?php
    $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    ?>
    " method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete all questions">
    </form>
```

Now, this is what should my form normally look like:
[image]

But this is what happens when I put in or out of the div tag inside my dynamic page file:
http://tinypic.com/images/404.gif

What am I doing wrong? what is going on? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have some CSS rules that change the appearance of `input` and `textarea` elements, probably something like:

```
input, textarea {
    border: none;
}
```

That’s why your `input` and `textarea` elements do not have a border. And the centered align might be inherited from a parent element.

Comment: I do not :( I checked that first

Comment: @IWalkedAway: Are you sure? Because I can see no other reason for that. Did you check with a tool that allows to see the styles applied to a certain element (like Safari’s WebInspector or the Firefox extension Firebug does)?

Comment: hey, thanks. google chrome's option "inspect element" helped me.
This is what caused the problem:
* {border:0px}

Comment: @IWalkedAway: And is there a rule that applies such a change on your elements?

Comment: yeah, that rule is: 
* {
border:0px;
}
it is what caused the problem, now everything works fine :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a CSS pro, but what I'd recommend is firing this up in Firefox after you download the add-on Firebug. Firebug will let you get right in there and mess with the CSS and HTML while it is running in the browser, so you can adjust things on the fly, turn on and off css elements, and isolate exactly what is causing the problem. Just find the div in the Firebug window and it will list every css element currently attached to it. From there, you should be able to move through the code and see where that weird CSS is coming from.